# Could this be considered duplicate content?

Tags: seo, search-engines, duplicate-content, googlebot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

I'm building a dating site at the moment. On the homepage I have a paginated list of all members on the site. Each page displays 10 members from newest to oldest. The pagination is simply "<< Prev" and "Next >>" links, so Googlebot should be able to crawl each and every member profile on the site.

Now the thing is, these profile listings also appear on other pages. A listing block such as:

```
-------------------------------------
<IMAGE>

Jill / 28 / Straight
New York, NY

Likes: long walks on the beach, vodka
-------------------------------------
```

Will appear on the `Homepage ---> www.mysite.com/page/2`

as well as on this category page `"Women seeking Men" ---> www.mysite.com/women-seeking-men/page/3`

So that's two places where the same listing block appears. Is this considered duplicate content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends. I'm assuming that on the profile page there will be more information than in the profile blocks, with a full profile on one page, and just a couple pieces of information in the blocks, with a link to the full profile. This isn't exactly "duplicate content" in the way search engines speak of. The issue of duplicate is more along these lines:

```
http://www.example.com/members/Jill <- Full profile for Jill
http://www.example.com/members/2541451 <- Same full profile for Jill
```

That has the EXACT SAME content being accessible from two different addresses. This is actually what canonical URLs were meant for. To tell the search engine that a page is a copy and to provide a single address that should be indexed. A canonical URL is not something that would come into play for a listing block as you mentioned.

This is what Google says (emphasis mine):

> Duplicate content generally refers to SUBSTANTIVE blocks of content within or across domains that either completely match other content or are appreciably similar.

Source: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359

I don't think a short clip in a listing block would meet this description.